# google-bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery for SEO reasons. I am a search TC and I am a little confused why you are not using the Google Forum as I thought that was standard. What I want to use BigQuery for is to pull when my competitors change data on their website and which pages that were changed. So I need the URL that was changed and when it was changed (date) so I can also pull the page title and description to see what they are doing different than I am.

Is there anyone that knows how to use BigQuery to pull:

1. Date the page was changed
2. URL
3. Title
4. Description

Comment: It seems you do not understand what BigQuery is or what it is used for. I suggest reading the docs, and then re-formulating your question(s): https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/what-is-bigquery

Answer (score 6):

We've switched to using Stack Overflow for support for many of our developer products, such as BigQuery.  There's a great community here on StackOverflow, and the interface for formatting technical questions and interacting with the community is fantastic.

BigQuery does not collect the data for you-- it's a cloud service for performing ad hoc queries on massive datasets.  Before first performing the queries, you need to upload the data to the service (as a CSV format).

So, if you have a job which collects this data -- URL, title, description, date and perhaps a hash of the webpage, you could potentially ingest a CSV file of this data into BigQuery and use it to understand when webpages have changed.

Of course, there are also 3rd-party services (such as Changedetection.com) which may be easier to use for your purposes.